# Как вывести Item из ItemList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Как выводить один элемент в `main`, соответствующий той ссылке, которую кликаешь слева?

Я записываю `index` в `id` и пытаюсь потом вывести данные, у которых `id` и `index` совпадают. Смотрю на `refs`, но что то мне кажется не туда. Еще чувствую, что придумываю лажу, есть способ проще.
Данные хранятся в `store redux`. Сейчас у меня справа выводятся все итемы. А нужно только один, который выбрал. А по умолчанию чтобы был первый например.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Item } from 'semantic-ui-react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          currentClient: [],
          isToggleOn: true
      };
      this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(e) {
      this.setState(state => ({
            isToggleOn: !state.isToggleOn
      }));
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.testStore);
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <aside>
              <Item.Group link>
                  {this.props.testStore.map((arrayItem, index) =>

                      <Item key={index} id={index} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                          <Item.Image size='tiny' src={arrayItem.general.avatar} />

                          <Item.Content>
                              <Item.Header>{`${arrayItem.general.firstName} ${arrayItem.general.lastName}`}</Item.Header>
                          </Item.Content>
                      </Item>
                  )}
              </Item.Group>
          </aside>
          <main>
              {this.props.testStore.map((arrayItem, index) =>

                  <div key={index}>
                      <img src={arrayItem.general.avatar} alt=""/>
                      <p>{arrayItem.address.street}</p>
                  </div>
              )}
          </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
    state => ({
        testStore: state
    }),
    dispatch => ({})
)(App);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

при клике на элемент, надо записать его index в локальный стор, например как id, затем отфильтровать массив по этому id:
`this.props.testStore.filter((arrayItem, index) => index === this.state.id)`,
получится массив из 1 нашего элемента, дальше уже можно отрендерить через `.map`